# Better upper bound involving linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $\mathcal{A} \colon \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a linear operator. For any given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $t > 0$. Denote:
$$ z = t \left( x - y \right) + \mathcal{A}^{*} \left( \mathcal{A} y - \mathcal{A} x \right) . $$
Then it can be seen that
\begin{equation}
\left\lVert z \right\rVert \leq t \left\lVert x - y \right\rVert + \left\lVert \mathcal{A}^{*} \left( \mathcal{A} y - \mathcal{A} x \right) \right\rVert \leq \left( t + \left\lVert \mathcal{A} \right\rVert ^{2} \right) \left\lVert x - y \right\rVert .
\end{equation}
However notice that
$$ z = \left( t \mathrm{Id} - \mathcal{A}^{*} \mathcal{A} \right) \left( x - y \right) $$
and thus we can deduce
$$ \left\lVert z \right\rVert = \left\lVert t \mathrm{Id} - \mathcal{A}^{*} \mathcal{A} \right\rVert \left\lVert x - y \right\rVert . $$
I guess that if I can find another upper bound for $t \mathrm{Id} - \mathcal{A}^{*} \mathcal{A}$ then I can improve the etimate for $\left\lVert z \right\rVert$ but I don't know how.

**Edit**

> The main point is to express the formula $\left\lVert t \mathrm{Id} - \mathcal{A}^{*} \mathcal{A} \right\rVert$ in term of $t$ and $\left\lVert \mathcal{A}^{*} \mathcal{A} \right\rVert$.

**Update** (Thanks to @mechanodroid)

> One idea is to try to prove $\left\lVert t \mathrm{Id} - \mathcal{A}^{*} \mathcal{A} \right\rVert = \left\lvert t - \left\lVert \mathcal{A} \right\rVert ^{2} \right\rvert$.
>   Suppose that $t \geq \left\lVert \mathcal{A} \right\rVert ^{2}$ then he proved that $t - \left\lVert \mathcal{A} \right\rVert ^{2} \leq \left\lvert t \left\lVert x \right\rVert ^{2} - \left\lVert \mathcal{A}x \right\rVert ^{2} \right\rvert$.
>   If we can prove that $\left\lvert t \left\lVert x \right\rVert ^{2} - \left\lVert \mathcal{A}x \right\rVert ^{2} \right\rvert \leq t - \left\lVert \mathcal{A} \right\rVert ^{2}$ then the claim is obtained.

Comment: If I understood correctly, basically you wish to find the operator norm $\|t\cdot I - A^*A\|$ in terms of $t$ and $\|A\|$, and so far you have $\|t\cdot I - A^*A\|\le t + \|A\|^2$. It seems the equality won't hold in general, because if you take $A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ as $A = \sqrt{t}\cdot I$ we have:

$$\left\|t\cdot I - \left(\sqrt{t}\cdot I\right)^*\left(\sqrt{t}\cdot I\right)\right\| = \|0\| = 0 < 2t = t + \left\|\sqrt{t}\cdot I\right\|^2$$

Comment: $A^*A$ is diagonalisable with real positive or null eigenvalues $\lambda_i^2$ with a unitary diagonalizing matrix So $||z||$ is reduced to study the value $||\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1^2-t,...,\lambda_n^2-t)||$, but it's not directly related to $||A||$. Don't know if that really helps.

Comment: @mechanodroid Yes! You understood correctly. I guess I should add your description to the question. It looks not very attractive at this moment. In addition, I knew that the equality would not hold in general that's why I asked for a better bound

Comment: @zwim Thanks so much for your suggestion. Any idea not lead to sum of two terms are appreciated at this moment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on the comment of @zwim:

The following proposition will be useful.

> Let $T : X \to X$ be a self-adjoint operator on a inner product space $X$. Then we have:
>
> $$\|T\| = \sup\big\{\left|\left\langle Tx, x\right\rangle\right| : x \in X, \|x\| =1\big\}$$
>
> Proof for finite-dimensional $X$:
>
> For any $x\in X, \|x\| =1$ we have $$|\langle Tx, x\rangle| \le \|Tx\|\|x\| \le \|T\|\|x\|^2 =\|T\|$$
>
> Thus $\sup\big\{|\langle Tx, x\rangle| : x \in X, \|x\| =1\big\} \le \|T\|$.
>
> For the reverse inequality, let $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $X$ in which $T$ is diagonalized, that is $Te_i = \lambda_ie_i$ for some $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$. Denote $M = \max\{|\lambda_1|, \ldots, |\lambda_n|\}$.
>
> We have $M \le \sup\big\{|\langle Tx, x\rangle| : x \in X, \|x\| =1\big\}$ since $\left|\langle Te_i, e_i\rangle\right| = |\lambda_i|$.
>
> For any $x\in X, \|x\| =1$ we have:
>   \begin{align}\|Tx\|^2 &= \left\langle \sum_{i=1}^n \langle x, e_i\rangle Te_i,\sum_{i=1}^n \langle x, e_i\rangle Te_i\right\rangle\\
> &= \left\langle \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \langle x, e_i\rangle e_i,\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \langle x, e_i\rangle e_i\right\rangle\\
> &= \sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|^2 |\langle x, e_i\rangle|^2\\
> &\le M^2  \sum_{i=1}^n |\langle x, e_i\rangle|^2\\
> &= M^2 \|x\|^2
> \end{align}
>
> Thus, $\|T\| \le M$.
>
> We have:
>
> $$\sup\big\{|\langle Tx, x\rangle| : x \in X, \|x\| =1\big\} \le \|T\| \le M \le \sup\big\{|\langle Tx, x\rangle| : x \in X, \|x\| =1\big\}$$
>
> So $\|T\| = \sup\big\{|\langle Tx, x\rangle| : x \in X, \|x\| =1\big\} = M$.

Now in our case, notice that $t\cdot I - A^*A$ is a self-adjoint operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Therefore
$$\|t\cdot I - A^*A\| = \max\big\{\left|t - \lambda_1\right|, \ldots, \left|t - \lambda_n\right|\big\}$$

where $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of $A^*A$, which are real nonnegative numbers.

As you can see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/230058/113769), there seems to be no simple relationship between the eigenvalues of $A^*A$ and $A$.

Comment: actually the other case is more important for me. but I would keep looking for the answer based on this direction. thank you again!

Comment: I don't think this holds. For instance for $x$ real and $t=x^2$, if $A=\begin{pmatrix}x&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ then $tI-A^*A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&x^2\end{pmatrix}$ so $||A||_1^2=||tI-A^*A||_1=x^2$ not $t-||A||_1^2=0$.

Comment: @zwim Ok, that resolves my second attempt.